# In Docusign ,envelope status reports (in console -> reports section) we get a field total pages;How to get the same through DocuSign API?

Tags: api, docusignapi

I have explored the envelope API-https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/ but unable to find out the exact call details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EnvelopeDocuments::List](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list/)  method of the eSignature API:

```
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents
```

For each document you'll get the number of pages and then it's just a matter of totaling the envelope's documents.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply!..Yes that will give me pages per envelope but we have hundreds of account and thousands of envelopes associated with it and we just need total no. of pages per account and not against each envelope. Is there a way to do it more efficiently without calling it thousands of time?

Comment: I'm afraid not. This is not something that is optimized for, so, yes, you would have to do the above.